# Python how to change a variable that is referenced in a list

Tags: python, list

```
import random
warrior = 'Warrior'
mage = 'Mage'
warlock = 'Warlock'
paladin = 'Paladin'
firstList = [warrior, mage, warlock, paladin]
print(firstList[0], firstList[1], firstList[2], firstList[3])
firstNumber = random.randint(0, 3)
firstList[firstNumber] = '*taken*'
print(firstList[0], firstList[1], firstList[2], firstList[3])
secondList = [paladin, warlock, mage, warrior]
print(secondList[0], secondList[1], secondList[2], secondList[3])
```

Let's say the random number picks 0
I realized that the 9th line actually just changes the list entry to "*taken*", instead of changing the 'warrior' variable that entry refers to into "*taken*". Is there any way to do that?

Forgive the WoW references.

Comment: Strings are immutable.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use dictionaries instead:

```
taken = {'warrior': False, 'mage': False, 'warlock': False, 'paladin': False}
names = {'warrior': 'Warrior', 'mage': 'Mage', 'warlock': 'Warlock', 'paladin': 'Paladin'}
```

or:

```
taken = dict.fromkeys(('warrior', 'mage', 'warlock', 'paladin'), False)
names = {character: character.capitalize() for character in taken}
```

then pick a random character:

```
from random import choice
picked = choice(list(names.keys()))
taken[picked] = True
print('Picked:', names[picked])
```

You really do not want to use separate local identifiers to represent a group of characters, that only complicates matters.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this using your current technique.  I suggest using the technique in Martijn Pieters' answer.

Just to expand a tiny bit on why you can't:

Your variables are all `string` objects, which are immutable (as noted by Peter Wood).  Immutable means cannot be changed - when you change the variable, you are making a new object.  If you were to be doing the same thing with a mutable type, then this would be possible

```
>>> list_1 = []
>>> list_2 = []
>>> main_list = [list_1, list_2]
>>> main_list[1].append(5)
>>> print(list_2)
[5]
```

For more on mutability, see:
[Immutable vs Mutable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types-python)
[Which of these are immutable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656998/which-of-these-are-immutable-in-python)
http://stsdas.stsci.edu/pyraf/python_quick_tour.html#PyMutability

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an object oriented approach?

```
from random import choice

class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, name, taken=False):
        self.name = name
        self.taken = taken
    def get_taken(self):
        self.taken = True
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.taken and '{} (taken)'.format(self.name) or self.name


class Team(list):
    def take_someone(self, number=None):
        if number is None:
            choice(self).get_taken()
        else:
            self[number].get_taken()


myTeam = Team([Character("Warrior"),
               Character("Mage"),
               Character("Warlock")])
print myTeam
```

[Warrior, Mage, Warlock]

```
myTeam.take_someone()

print myTeam
```

[Warrior, Mage, Warlock (taken)]

Now you even can initialize a character as "`taken`", and you can either let your `myTeam` object choose some random character to be taken using `myTeam.take_someone()`, or you can take a character by index. e.g. `myTeam.take_someone(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with two sets, `untaken` and `taken`, since this seems like something where order is irrelevant.

So you'd choose members and move them between sets with something like

```
import random
taken = set()
untaken = set(['Mage','Warlock','Warrior','Paladin'])
chosen = random.sample(untaken,1)
taken.add(chosen)
untaken.remove(chosen)
```